# Extract upcoming events using Google Calendar API - VB.NET

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using this VB code to retrieve the upcomming events from my calendar

```
Private Sub LoadCalendars()
    Dim service As CalendarService = GetCalendarService()
    Dim objCalendarListRequest As CalendarListResource.ListRequest = service.CalendarList.List
    objCalendars = objCalendarListRequest.Execute()
    If objCalendars Is Nothing Or objCalendars.Items.Count = 0 Then
        '** No calendars.  Something is wrong.  Give up and die.
        MsgBox("No calendars found?  That's weird.")
        End
    Else
        For Each objCal As Data.CalendarListEntry In objCalendars.Items
            Console.WriteLine(objCal.Summary)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

But I'm not able to :

1. retrive only the 'primary' calendar
2. retrieve only the upcomming events

I found out several examples in C#, but I need it in VB.

This example in C# works fine and does exactly what I need, my issue how to do the same in VB..?

```
// Define parameters of request.
        EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request.ShowDeleted = false;
        request.SingleEvents = true;
        request.MaxResults = 10;
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
```

Some suggestion..?
Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
Dim request As EventsResource.ListRequest = service.Events.List(objCal.Id)
request.TimeMin = Now.Date()
request.ShowDeleted = False
request.SingleEvents = True
request.MaxResults = 10
request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime
```

Answer (score 0):

service.CalendarList.List doesnt do what you think it does.

A users calendarlist is the list at the bottom left of the web application.  Calendars need to be manually added to that by the user.  This is not a list of all the calendars a user has access to.

You need to find the calendar id yourself and then use that. The easiest way is to find it in the web application under settings.

Comment: Hi Linda thank you by the replay. this code is working. I'm able to retrieve all of my calendar and also able to retrive all events. So the code is working. What I need to do is to select only the upcomming event of my primary calendar.

Comment: service.Events.List("primary");  <-- you added primary thats only going to show the events in your primary calendar.

Comment: Yes, correct. This is the goal.